How to Run C in VS Code
Error I Get

Whenever I try to run any C/C++ code in VS Code, I get this error pop up, and idk what to do. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code C/C++ extension, but I get the same thing
I click run like I would any other program, then I get this image, and either option I click on, I get the error
Before the error


Ok, VS Code doesn't come with a compiler so even if you install an extension it won't work until you install a compiler as well.  If you have installed it then if you edit your post with the contents of tasks.json (build instructions), launch.json (debugger settings), and c_cpp_properties.json (compiler path and IntelliSense settings) that would help.  Have a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

If you don't have a compiler, the MSys2 environment that provides the gcc/MinGW compilers is very good. Works well with VSCode and provides an excellent Linux development environment from its very good terminal.

To me, this looks like the launch.json file still contains the text "enter program name, for example..." in the place where you should enter the actual name of the program you are writing.


Verify that the code is being compiled, and an executable is being created. A simple GCC command like gcc main.c -o main.exe will work. 2. Make sure the executable main.exe is mentioned in your launch.json file in the .vscode folder of your project. If you need more details check out my guide Setup Guide for C/C++ Programming on VSCode


you should check the launch.json file. thats where the visual studio code parameters are. if its messed up it might do something to prevent it. you could also try deleting the launch.json file and running it again to make a new one. other than that I don't know. i don't code much with c/c+/c++ but I hope this does help! there also might be something in your vscode settings. hope this helps :3

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
